# Java: Bisection Method

Tags: java, math

```
package bisection.method;



public class BisectionMethod {

    static float f(float x){
        return (float) (Math.pow(x,2) - 4*x + 4 - Math.log(x));
    }

    static float bisection_method(float a, float b, float tol){
        float midpoint = 0;
        if(f(a)*f(b)>0){
            System.out.println("No Root Found");
        }
        else{
            while (((b-a)/2.0) > tol){
                midpoint = (float) ((float)(a+b)/2.0);
                if (f(midpoint) == 0){
                return (midpoint);
                }
                else if ((f(a)*f(midpoint)) < 0){
                    b = midpoint;
                }
                else{
                    a = midpoint;
                }
            }
        }
        return(midpoint);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float answer = bisection_method(1,2, (float) 0.000000001);
    System.out.print(answer);
}
```

This is my code. I'm creating a bisection method through Java that inputs 2 numbers and a tolerance and passes it through the function. There are no errors in the code, but when I run the program it comes back  with nothing. It just keeps running. My question is, is it because it is taking a long time to come back, or am I missing something entirely?. Thank you for the help.
-Matthew

Comment: If a program doesn't do what you expect (and instead does what you told it to do), observe the steps it takes by using the debugging features of your IDE. Especially single-stepping through your program will turn out helpful very often.

Comment: Your program gets `Time limit exceeded` verdicts! The condition in `while` loop `((b-a)/2.0) > tol` never become false. As mentioned, observe each step. I think there is a mathematical error in the `while` loop.

Comment: All of your casting to `float` would be unnecessary if you used `2.0f` or `2.f` instead of `2.0`. (Mind you, the cast in `(float)(a+b)` is unnecessary anyway, the expression is already a float).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to print the computation and the tolerance and you can see it never converges properly.  If you reduce your tolerance it will work.  But why are you using `floats` instead of `doubles`?

```
while (((b-a)/2.0) > tol){
    System.out.println((b-a)/2.0 + " " + tol); // <-- print statement
    midpoint = (float) ((float)(a+b)/2.0);
    if (f(midpoint) == 0){
    return (midpoint);
    }
    else if ((f(a)*f(midpoint)) < 0){
        b = midpoint;
    }
    else{
        a = midpoint;
    }
}
```

I would check the tolerance as follows:

```
float lastMidPoint = ... // initialize to some value.
while (Math.abs(((b-a)/2.0) - lastMidPoint) >= tol){
   ...
   ...
   lastMidPoint = midpoint; // after recalculation
   ...
}
```

When I did the above, your program converged.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I should change it to all doubles and it worked perfectly afterwards! I appreciate it greatly!